# C# How can I capture undo history excel to place it back after event

Tags: c#, events, excel-2007, undo

It is a known problem that using event handlers in excel kill the undo buffer, I searched the internet for a solution but could not find it. So I was wondering if i could just capture the undo buffer as the first thing in my event; do what ever I want in my handler and then place the buffer back to where it belongs. Or is maybe this bug solved in excel 2010?